# How to include class from complicated modules(paypal_permissions gem)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, paypal

**EDITD**

I'm sorry, that didn't post ALL

My controller:

```
   def get_basic_personal_data merchant
     access_token = merchant.ppp_access_token
     verifier = merchant.ppp_access_token_verifier
     ::PAYPAL_PERMISSIONS_GATEWAY.get_basic_personal_data(access_token, verifier)
   end
```

I have module:

```
 module ActiveMerchant #:nodoc:
  module Billing #:nodoc:
   class PaypalPermissionsGateway < ActiveMerchant::Billing::Gateway # :nodoc
  ...
   def get_basic_personal_data
...
end
```

I need to use this method to get data from PayPal, so I need to include it into merchant_controller, but I don't know how.

I want to use in views something like:

```
   <%=  @merchant.get_basic_personal_data.email%>
```

But I constantly get error:

```
      undefined method `get_basic_personal_data' for #<Merchant:0x618ea78>
```

**EDIT**

Errors from Full trace:

```
  activemodel (3.2.3) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
 activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:148:in `method_missing'
```

What I should do ?

Comment: My understanding is that you want to make the method `get_basic_personal_data`, which is a member of class `PaypalPermissionGateway`, available as a member of your `Merchant` model. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your model load the module with `include ActiveMerchant::Billing` then you should be able to do `@merchant.get_basic_personal_data`.

Comment: I was hoping this would at least get you pointed in the right direction. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mixin your module with the `PaypalPermissionGateway` try adding the following line after your module definition:

```
PaypalPermissionGateway.send(:include, ActiveMerchant)
```

You may need to alter the class name, to include its namespace.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you have defined your method `get_basic_personal_data` on your controller, but you are trying to call it from your `@merchant` instance. But `get_basic_personal_data` isn't defined on your `Merchant` model, and cannot be called like that. What you are doing is tantamount to the following:

```
class A
end

class B
  def method_b
    ...
  end
end

a = new A()
a.method_b()
```

I.e., it won't work.

What you should be doing, according to how you've layed out your code, is the following:

```
get_basic_personal_data(@merchant)
```

By default, you won't be able to access your controller's methods from your views until you expose them. One way to do this is with `helper_method`. E.g.:

```
class MerchantsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :get_basic_personal_data

  ...

  def get_basic_personal_data merchant
    ...
  end
end
```